# TCL Obtain the Output of a Completed Background Process

Tags: tcl

I need to run a script in parallel on several hosts but once complete on an account it needs to move onto the next account instead of waiting for parallel host to complete on its account. The code I have below works for this.

So the issue I'm having is I need to be able to record the output of the commands run on each account's once they have completed. So in the example below I'd need the echo "account@host" output from each of the runtimes and the exit code that each of them produce to ensure each command was successfully run.

How would I go about capturing the output?

My code is as follows:

```
set HOST(host1) "account1 account2 account3 account4"
set HOST(host2) "account1 account3"

# Let make our variables we'll edit and manipulate as we go.
set hostList     [array names HOST]
set activeHosts  ""
set background   ""

set cont 1
while { $cont == 1 } {
    foreach host [array names HOST] {
        if { [lsearch $activeHosts $host] == -1 && $HOST($host) != "" } {

            set script {
puts [exec ssh -A -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null @var1@@@var2@ "echo @var1@@@var2@"]
            }

            set script [string map [list @var1@ [lindex $HOST($host) 0]] $script]
            set script [string map [list @var2@ $host] $script]

            set chan [open |[list [info nameofexecutable] <<$script 2>@stderr]]
            dict set res $chan command $script
            fconfigure $chan -blocking 0

            # Let's keep a backup of what's running in the background
            lappend activeHosts $host
            lappend background  $chan
            set CHANMAP($chan) $host
        } else {
            # Check the processes in the background to see how they are going.
            foreach chan $background {
                if { [eof $chan] } {
                    #############################################
                    # PROCESS HAS ENDED READ THE OUTPUT SOMEHOW #
                    #############################################

                    # We have completed the task on the account / host let's remove it so we don't run on it again
                    set i [lsearch $activeHosts $CHANMAP($chan)]
                    set activeHosts [lreplace $activeHosts $i $i]

                    #Remove the account we've run this on from the list
                    set HOST($CHANMAP($chan)) [lreplace $HOST($CHANMAP($chan)) 0 0]

                    if { $HOST($CHANMAP($chan)) == "" } {
                        # Once we've run out of accounts on the host remove the host
                        set j [lsearch $hostList $CHANMAP($chan)]
                        set hostList [lreplace $hostList $j $j]
                    }

                    fconfigure $chan -blocking 1

                    if { [set idx [lsearch -exact $background $chan]] >= 0 } {
                        set background [lreplace $background $idx $idx]
                    }
                    catch [close $chan] cres copts
                    dict set res $chan result $cres
                    dict set res $chan options $copts
                } else {
                    puts -nonewline [read $chan]
                }
            }
        }
        # If there is nothing left in the hostList then we've run on everything.
        if { [llength $hostList] == 0 } {
            set cont 0
            break
        }
    }

    # Let's wait depending on the task usage so we don't hammer the CPU
    if { $taskLength == "low" } {
        after 100
    } else {
        after 2000
    }
}
```

I'm using tcl version 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

You want a slightly more complex runner script.

```
set script [string map [list @var1@ [lindex $HOST($host) 0] @var2@ $host] {
    set code [catch {
        exec ssh -A -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
                @var1@@@var2@ "echo @var1@@@var2@"
    } msg opt]
    puts [list $code $msg $opt]
    exit
}]
```

You can then launch that script, collect the result when it arrives, and process it to discover what happened.

```
set chan [open |[list [info nameofexecutable] <<$script 2>@stderr]]
fconfigure $chan readable [list apply {{chan host} {
    lassign [read $chan] code msg opt
    close $chan
    if {$opt == 0} {
        # Normal exit; $msg has what subsubprocess wrote to stdout
        puts "$host --> $msg"
    } else if {[string match CHILDSTATUS* [dict get $opt -errorcode]]} {
        set exitcode [lindex [dict get $opt -errorcode] 2]
        # Error; exit code now extracted
        puts "$host -($exitcode)-> $msg"
    } else {
        # Something more serious occurred
        puts stderr "PROBLEM($code): $msg $opt"
    }
}} $chan $host]
```

As long as you run the event loop, you can launch almost any number of these in parallel (though you probably want to stop short of a hundred; most operating systems aren't configured to have that sort of load dropped on them at once) and Tcl will keep track of it all for you.

---

The real trick is to use `catch` with *two* variables, then package those values across the pipe, then unpack and figure out what happened. Packing with `list` and unpacking with `lassign` is very easy, and you don't need to worry about blocking reads or buffering since the wrapping subprocess always writes everything at once and (flushes and) exits straight after.

Comment: In Tcl 8.6, you can use pipes in more sophisticated ways to get stderr and stdout redirected separately.

Comment: For the line with "readable" in it i'm getting the following error: 
bad option "readable": should be one of -blocking, -buffering, -buffersize, -encoding, -eofchar, or -translation

Guessing it's not available in 8.5?

Comment: The "fconfigure ..." command should read "fileevent ..." and it is available in 8.5.

Comment: Could be my lack of knowledge, but whereabouts do you trigger and capture the outputs of the fileevent? I thought it would be when reading chan ("read $chan" or "eof $chan" lines).